# Finding the smallest stretching factor of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-equations, condition-number

I'm going through my class notes and trying to follow along with the math here:

[image]

However, in the last step I'm unsure why you are able to 'divide' the $\mathbf{y}$ vector out of the norm $||A^{-1}\mathbf{y}||$, is that a valid operation since it's a scalar value?

Comment: Given a square matrix $M$, the definition of $\|M\|$ being used is  $$\| M \| = \max_{\mathbf{y} \neq 0} \frac{\| M \mathbf{y} |}{\| \mathbf{y}\|} $$ Or if the norm has been defined othewise, this must be an ensuing property. So the last step is not a "division", but simply an application of the definition of norm.

Comment: okay, i didnt see that thank you!